# Sync multiple devices without internet React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, offline-storage

I have connect multiple android devices to the same WiFi network but internet connection is not working. I want to sync data between all devices. Is there anyway to do the data synchronization on local network without internet ? in short I want to sync data between devices using local network.

Comment: You could provide a server with a database within the same network, which handles the datasharing with a application which exposes a api for the clients to use

Answer (score 0):

Sure! It's not trivial though.

If you're looking to do this without using a "static" server or database or similar on the local network,

- you'll need a way for the devices to be able to discover each other (the easiest is manually, i.e. by entering an IP address)
- listen to network requests – on one device if you're looking for a star/server-client topology, or on all of them if you're looking for a mesh where all devices sync with all of them
- have the devices talk to each other to sync data as required.

Comment: I want database also.

Comment: In that case, just set up the database/server/... on your local network and connect to it via IP address instead of an Internet DNS name.